# How can I tell if my memory has been released securely by a PHP application?

Tags: php, security, securezeromemory

This might be better suited for security.stackexchange.com, but I'm curious about PHP in particular.

I'm working with openssl in an application and I notice the free operations for the openssl resources. This could very well just be just a generic release of memory, but given the cryptographic nature it may be handled as a special case.

AFAIK inside the application space there is no way to ensure a variable is deleted from memory. However, in Zend land, do the C extensions clean up known sensitive data, or do they just release the memory? Does `openssl_pkey_free` release the memory securely? How can I go about making an assertion that it has been released securely to apply it to other extensions I may be curious about in the future?

I'm not a security analyst, so my definition of securely is rather vague.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR: No.

Before I even look, my answer is: Since PHP is a dynamic language, you should **assume it's not cleared** until proven otherwise (e.g. with Volatility). According to former FreeBSD security officer Colin Percival, ["Zeroing Buffers is Insufficient"](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-06-zeroing-buffers-is-insufficient.html) -- so it might not even matter.

But that's an incredibly boring answer. What's under the hood?

### What does openssl_pkey_free() do?

`openssl_pkey_free()` is defined by PHP in [ext/openssl/openssl.c#545](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.7/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L545):

```
void EVP_PKEY_free(EVP_PKEY *x)
{
    int i;

    if (x == NULL)
        return;

    i = CRYPTO_add(&x->references, -1, CRYPTO_LOCK_EVP_PKEY);
#ifdef REF_PRINT
    REF_PRINT("EVP_PKEY", x);
#endif
    if (i > 0)
        return;
#ifdef REF_CHECK
    if (i < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_free, bad reference count\n");
        abort();
    }
#endif
    EVP_PKEY_free_it(x);
    if (x->attributes)
        sk_X509_ATTRIBUTE_pop_free(x->attributes, X509_ATTRIBUTE_free);
    OPENSSL_free(x);
}

static void EVP_PKEY_free_it(EVP_PKEY *x)
{
    if (x->ameth && x->ameth->pkey_free) {
        x->ameth->pkey_free(x);
        x->pkey.ptr = NULL;
    }
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
    if (x->engine) {
        ENGINE_finish(x->engine);
        x->engine = NULL;
    }
#endif
}
```

As you can see, it calls a function called `EVP_PKEY_free()`, which is defined by openssl in [/crypto/evp/p_lib.c#L376](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2a/crypto/evp/p_lib.c#L376):

```
void EVP_PKEY_free(EVP_PKEY *x)
{
    int i;

    if (x == NULL)
        return;

    i = CRYPTO_add(&x->references, -1, CRYPTO_LOCK_EVP_PKEY);
#ifdef REF_PRINT
    REF_PRINT("EVP_PKEY", x);
#endif
    if (i > 0)
        return;
#ifdef REF_CHECK
    if (i < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_free, bad reference count\n");
        abort();
    }
#endif
    EVP_PKEY_free_it(x);
    if (x->attributes)
        sk_X509_ATTRIBUTE_pop_free(x->attributes, X509_ATTRIBUTE_free);
    OPENSSL_free(x);
}
```

It does some sanity checks then calls `OPENSSL_free()`, which is just [an alias](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2a/crypto/crypto.h#L390) for `CRYPTO_free()`.

Finally, `CRYPTO_free()` is defined [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2a/crypto/mem.c#L316):

```
void CRYPTO_free(void *str)
{
    if (free_debug_func != NULL)
        free_debug_func(str, 0);
#ifdef LEVITTE_DEBUG_MEM
    fprintf(stderr, "LEVITTE_DEBUG_MEM:         < 0x%p\n", str);
#endif
    free_func(str);
    if (free_debug_func != NULL)
        free_debug_func(NULL, 1);
}
```

It seems to just call `free_func()` in the typical case, which is a pointer to `free()`. At no point in these operations did I see any attempt to zero out memory.

### But I really want to zero memory in PHP. How can I?!

If you can install PECL extensions, [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) offers [`\Sodium\memzero()`](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/03-utilities-helpers.md#memzero) in addition to [secure memory allocation utilities](http://doc.libsodium.org/helpers/memory_management.html).

Please remember that zeroing memory is a mitigation strategy for when a compromise happens. If your PHP code can read the private key from disk (or from a database), the attacker can probably replay the code and steal the key directly. The way to protect against this is store your keys in a [hardware security module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) and never touch it directly.

Comment: I kind of expected that to be the case, but wasn't sure if they possibly had some clever way to destroy the released memory. My application gets a random password sent to it on an event and it requests the corresponding key (single use per token) from a vault. So my biggest problem would be if someone could read the memory, but if they can I have bigger problems than whether or not my signing key is compromised.

Comment: There are some best practices you can follow to help. Store it in a class constant rather than a private variable if you're concerned about serialization and/or stack traces. Keep your crypto operations isolated to a separate machine than the rest of the network (especially the database) -- this is basically what a HSM does.